# Laravel Debugbar few tabs are not showing e.g. Route, Auth, Session, Gate

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel Debugbar https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar with Laravel 7.x according to documentation it should be show this
[image]

but my debugbar missing few tabs Route, Auth, Session, Gate etc. please see below

[image]
Please Help i can get above shown tabs
Regards,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Care to share your Debugbar conf? Have you tried doing a `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: 'providers' => [
.....
'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',
....


'aliases' => [ 
....
'DebugBar'  => 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade',

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:clear` use resolve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publish the config debugbar.php in /config

> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"

you can customize tabs in the config/debugbar.php :

```
...
'collectors' => [
    'phpinfo'         => true,  // Php version
    'messages'        => true,  // Messages
    'time'            => true,  // Time Datalogger
    'memory'          => true,  // Memory usage
    'exceptions'      => true,  // Exception displayer
    'log'             => true,  // Logs from Monolog (merged in messages if enabled)
    'db'              => true,  // Show database (PDO) queries and bindings
    'views'           => true,  // Views with their data
    'route'           => true,  // Current route information
    'auth'            => false, // Display Laravel authentication status
    'gate'            => true,  // Display Laravel Gate checks
    'session'         => true,  // Display session data
    'symfony_request' => true,  // Only one can be enabled..
    'mail'            => true,  // Catch mail messages
    'laravel'         => false, // Laravel version and environment
    'events'          => false, // All events fired
    'default_request' => false, // Regular or special Symfony request logger
    'logs'            => false, // Add the latest log messages
    'files'           => false, // Show the included files
    'config'          => false, // Display config settings
    'cache'           => false, // Display cache events
    'models'          => true,  // Display models
],
....
```

don't forget to do

> php artisan config:clear

if you use config cache

Comment: Thanks I followed it also

Answer (score 2):

I tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:clear` and it resolved my problem thanks to all to help me[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Laravel 8.x and the Debugbar was not showing the Auth tab. This seems to be the default setting. I published it using the instructions above, and edited the `config/debugbar.php` file setting 'auth' to true. What I missed, *since I am new to PHP/Laravel*, is that I should have edited the `config/debugbar.php` and not the `vendor/barryvdh/config/debugbar.php`. Once I edited the correct file, the tab was displayed. Thanks to all who contributed.